# Changing python shebang line during execution

Tags: python, linux, bash

I've a script having a shebang line like:

/home/user1/.virtualenvs/prj1/bin/python

. In some cases I'd need to change the python version of the running script to

/home/user2/.virtualenvs/prj2/bin/python

.

Is there any possibility to achieve this somehow (without using wrapper files)?

Comment: If the script is already running, the shebang has already been read and acted on, so even if you could change it, that would have no effect. You can't tell the running interpreter that the shell ought to have started a different interpreter instead, and expect useful results.

Comment: The closest thing I can see to this would be to re-execute the script under the other python interpreter, with something like an [`os.exec*()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl).

Comment: maybe run script directly as `/home/user2/.virtualenvs/prj2/bin/python  script.py`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this shebang line :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

so that in your virtual environment `prj1`, it will run :

```
/home/user1/.virtualenvs/prj1/bin/python
```

and in your virtual environment `prj2`, it will run :

```
/home/user2/.virtualenvs/prj2/bin/python
```